# get a query which returns items associated with categories and subcategories?

Tags: sql, relational-database, left-join, relation

I want to get a query which returns all items that belong to a category and subcategories.

Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoriasProductos](
    [IdCategoria] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Descripcion] [text] NULL,
    [IdCategoriaPadre] [int] NULL,
    [Nivel] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CategoriasProductos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdCategoria] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Productos](
    [IdProducto] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [IdCategoria] [int] NULL,
    [IdAlmacen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Codigo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Descripcion] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Imagen] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StockMin] [int] NULL,
    [StockMax] [int] NULL,
    [Ancho] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Alto] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Largo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Peso] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Volumen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Material] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Presentacion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bitPrecioVentaUnico] [int] NULL,
    [PrecioCompra] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoCompra] [float] NULL,
    [PrecioVenta] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoVenta] [float] NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Productos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdProducto] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now to add some data (at least for the categories only)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ON
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (1, 1, N'0')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (2, 1, N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (3, 1, N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (4, 2, N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (5, 2, N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (6, 4, N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (7, 4, N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (10, 5, N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (11, 5, N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (14, 3, N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] ([IdCategoria], [IdCategoriaPadre], [Nivel]) VALUES (15, 3, N'2')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CategoriasProductos] OFF
```

(I only inserted the data that I know that will or might be requiered for the query. Also, I have more rows in my original database but inserted fewer just to not make this anymore convoluted)

Now, for the moment I tried this query out:

```
SELECT Productos.Codigo, Productos.Nombre, Productos.Descripcion, A.Nombre AS Categoria
FROM Productos LEFT OUTER JOIN
CategoriasProductos AS A ON Productos.IdCategoria = A.IdCategoria LEFT OUTER JOIN
CategoriasProductos AS B ON B.IdCategoriaPadre = A.IdCategoria LEFT OUTER JOIN
CategoriasProductos AS C ON C.IdCategoriaPadre = B.IdCategoria LEFT OUTER JOIN
CategoriasProductos AS D ON D.IdCategoriaPadre = C.IdCategoria
WHERE (A.IdCategoria = 1)
```

Also a picture of how I constructed the query:
http://imageshack.us/a/img841/7029/pruebau.jpg

Now... in the query, it states that if A.IdCategoria = 1, (in this case) it should display all products that their IdCategoria either equals to 1 or equals another value that is somehow linked to IdCategoria 1 (in the Categorias Table).

Another example could be if I instead type WHERE B.IdCategoria = 2...
Then it should only show products which have an IdCategoria of 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10 or 11.

I tried with this query and it did not work. Maybe I'm not using joins in the correct way...

I was wondering if someone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or what I have to add to the query to make it work...

I hope you can help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't provide data for the Productos table.

Comment: Also the CategoriasProductos insert is missing the Nombre column

Comment: My bad about Productos...
maybe I needed some examples there so it would be easier to state which products would show up...

Nombre means Name, so I don't think is so necessary in the example since that is only used for the user to recognize the product category... I only inserted the data that I know mightt be essential for the query

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` does not bring in *extra rows* to your result set.  It would allow you to bring in *extra columns*.

What you have is hierarchical categories.  There are many questions on SO and DBA.SE about how to deal with hierarchical categories.  SQL is not great at dealing with hierarchies so people often use tricks like [visitation numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:659653%20visitation%20numbers) (see also [Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)).  I've used such a technique many times with great success.

There is a [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) here on SO that provides a pretty good set of links to articles on the many other approaches that people use to deal with hierarchical data.  Keep in mind that each of these involves some form of compromise.  You just have to pick the one for which the trade-offs are most beneficial in your situation.